# ARIA - Skip reading input value in screen reader (NVDA/Windows)

Tags: html, aurelia, wai-aria, nvda

I'm trying to find a way to make screen readers like NVDA of Windows Narrator stop reading an input value and read the `aria-describedby` only instead.

Here's the case, I have a web component that is a mask-input field. Let's say it is configured with a phone mask set to `(___) ___-____` where underscore can only be numbers. Right now the screen reader would read `left parens, 3 lines,  right parens, space...` and so on and then read what I set as the `aria-describedby` value which would be something like "Phone number, 1231231234" which use the unmasked value of my component.

What I'd like, would be the screen reader to only say "Phone number, 1231231234" which is my `aria-describedby` value and skip the rest so it keeps short and avoid saying things that can confused impaired user..

A bit of background, maybe this can change a bit the response, my component is built with Aurelia, I'm leveraging the binding system to update the value.

Is this something possible? I there a few alternative? I'm I completely off-track with what I'm trying to achieve?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a lot you can do to maintain accessibility with this approach. It is very important for the screen reader to read out the contents of the input field, otherwise when a user types a number it will not tell them what that number is - also if they decide to go back a character or forward a character, the value will read the label and not something they've entered. I imagine the input mask you're using is using javascript to replace a masked character with the user submitted one on keypress?

It is generally best practice to outline what the required input format is in the label or in descriptive text associated with the label. This will allow sighted users to easily match the required format and also allow visually disabled users to use their keyboard to navigate the input value with full knowledge of what the desired format is. I've thrown together a quick example of this.

```html
<label for="textInput">Phone Number</label>
<span id="phoneDesc">Please use the following format: (xxx)xxx-xxxx</span>
<input id="textInput" type="text" aria-describedby="phoneDesc" />
```

It could also be helpful to look into the general usability of input masks - a lot of people tend to find them troublesome. 
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/stop-password-masking/

If you're determined to use them and don't mind a different approach from your 'line' based approach, maybe give politespace a try (I have not tried this, but it could be worth evaluating for your needs) 
https://github.com/filamentgroup/politespace

Comment: What if the input value is controlled elsewhere? In my case a date picker of the sorts. And instead of reading "01/01/2020" I want the screen reader to read "Monday January 1st 2020"?

Comment: @Pants I would recommend starting a new question with a code example. It is difficult to give any valuable insight without having a more full understanding of your requirements. In this case, you want to display 01/01/2020, but have 'Monday January 1st 2020' only on screen readers? I have more questions but comments leave little space. Please start a new question and provide a bit more details and I will be happy to help!